# Xamarin Forms Image Sizing in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, image-size

I'm having difficulties in sizing the image in the iOS devices. I placed 3 images in the Resource folder of the iOS project ( forest.png, forest@2x, forest@3x). Using different iOS devices, the image is displaying in the same size

```
<Image Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Source="forest"/>
```

[image: iOS]

[image: devices]

[image: forest][image: forest@2x][image: forest@3x]

Is there something wrong I'm doing, or something needs to be modified?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try without Aspect="AspectFit"  because it can be give the similar size with fit

Comment: Tried it, no changes :(

Comment: @mohammadanouti - Did you check the resolution of all the three images?

Comment: I edited the question with the dimensions of each image in the resources file

Comment: Try to put them in a image assert.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the expected behavior since `screen resolution/image size` ratio will be same.

If  you want to put an image that has same percentage area on all screens use `AbsoulteLayout` or `Grid` to place.

**i.e**(put an image that uses 60% of screen):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="Forest" Acpect="AspectFit"/>
</Grid>
```